# IBM Watson Discovery news curl forbidden error

Tags: websphere, ibm-watson, watson-discovery

Trying to query Watson discovery news with the following curl command and get error 403 forbidden. 
`curl -u "apikey":"{apikey}" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api/v1/environments/system/collections/news-en/query?version=2019-04-30&query=relations.action.lemmatized:acquire&count=3&filter=entities.text:IBM&return=text"`

I found documents on the IBM site to create and query your own environments but not help with how to access the news.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out my url was incorrect. I got this to work.

`curl -u "apikey":"{apikey}" "https://api.eu-gb.discovery.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/96a866f9-11bb-4b55-af26-a0f826807fec/v1/environments/system/collections/news-en/query?version=2019-04-30&query=enriched_title.semantic_roles:(action.normalized:acquire,object.entities:(type::Company))&count=3"`

Comment: yes, this happens to me often, the hostname differs with the region your service is running in.

Answer (score 0):

Your curl looks correct, which may indicate that your apikey is incorrect. Try running the curl command to list environments:

```
curl -u "apikey":"{apikey}" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api/v1/environments?version=2019-04-30"
```

that should verify that you have the correct apikey.